# Postman - 401 unauthorized status | Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, postman, http-status-code-401

I prepared very simple REST APi.
I am trying to do requests with postman but i get 401 Unauthorized. No matter what kind request it is. I have Windows 11 system, Java 11, Postman Version 9.8.2

Postman:

[image]

application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Spring Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class StudentsmanagerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StudentsmanagerApplication.class, args);
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

private StudentService studentService;

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getAllStudents() {
    List<Student> students = studentService.findAllStudent();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(students, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("find/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Student> getAllStudentsById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Student student = studentService.findStudentById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(student, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Student> addEmployee(@RequestBody Student student) {
    Student newStudent = studentService.addStudent(student);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(newStudent, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Student> updateStudent(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Student 
student) {
    Student updatedStudent = studentService.updateStudent(id, student);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedStudent, HttpStatus.UPGRADE_REQUIRED);
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteStudent(@PathVariable Long id) {
    studentService.deleteStudent(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

private StudentRepository studentRepository;

public Student addStudent(Student student) {
    student.setStudentCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return studentRepository.save(student);
}

public List<Student> findAllStudent() {
    return studentRepository.findAll();
}

public Student updateStudent(Long id, Student student) {

    Student studentById = studentRepository
            .findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new StudentNotFoundException("Student by id 
" + " doesn't Exist"));
    studentById.setName(student.getName());
    studentById.setLastName(student.getLastName());
    studentById.setEmail(student.getEmail());
    studentById.setPhone(student.getPhone());
    return studentRepository.save(studentById);

}

public Student findStudentById(Long id) {
    return studentRepository
            .findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new StudentNotFoundException("Student 
doesn't exist "));
}

public void deleteStudent(Long id) {
    studentRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Spring logs:

> 2022-01-08 10:53:19.661  INFO 20120 --- [           main] p.s.s.StudentsmanagerApplication         : Starting StudentsmanagerApplication using Java 11.0.13 on LAPTOP-9F9MO24J with PID 20120 (C:\Users\mkord\IdeaProjects\studentsmanager\target\classes started by mkord in C:\Users\mkord\IdeaProjects\studentsmanager)
> 2022-01-08 10:53:19.661  INFO 20120 --- [           main] p.s.s.StudentsmanagerApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
> 2022-01-08 10:53:20.539  INFO 20120 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
> 2022-01-08 10:53:20.596  INFO 20120 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 50 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.262  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.278  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.278  INFO 20120 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.422  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.422  INFO 20120 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1684 ms
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.662  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.703  INFO 20120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.3.Final
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.856  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
> 2022-01-08 10:53:21.976  INFO 20120 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2022-01-08 10:53:22.336  INFO 20120 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
> 2022-01-08 10:53:22.352  INFO 20120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
> 2022-01-08 10:53:22.968  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
> 2022-01-08 10:53:22.984  INFO 20120 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2022-01-08 10:53:23.032  WARN 20120 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
> 2022-01-08 10:53:23.824  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@36931450, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@451a4187, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6db04a6, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@630c3af3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4866e0a7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@66d44581, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@4ac0d49, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@74919649, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2ea4e762, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5c215642, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1317ac2c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7d07e04e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@426913c4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@38197e82, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5a07ae2f]
> 2022-01-08 10:53:23.914  INFO 20120 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
> 2022-01-08 10:53:23.930  INFO 20120 --- [           main] p.s.s.StudentsmanagerApplication         : Started StudentsmanagerApplication in 4.851 seconds (JVM running for 6.309)
> 2022-01-08 10:59:13.709  INFO 20120 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2022-01-08 10:59:13.709  INFO 20120 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2022-01-08 10:59:13.709  INFO 20120 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
> 2022-01-08 10:59:13.941  WARN 20120 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [184] milliseconds.

Thank You in advance for any suggestion

Comment: well you have obviously added spring security dependency so all your requests have to be authorized. Read some spring security tutorial on how to set it up correctly

Comment: Thanks @JAsgarov, i forgot about this dependency.